# Resizable table area PHP

Tags: php, html, css, mysql, html-table

I am trying to show a lot of results at once (like 25) but my program cut the results around the 5th record having area space still available, the results are in a table
created dynamically but seems that the area doesn't expand accordingly.

```
<div id="contenido" class="contenido">

 <div id="Tabs">
<ul style="cursor:pointer;">
<li id="li_tab1" onclick="tab('tab1')" >
           <a>&Uacute;ltimas alertas</a>  </li>
    <li id="li_tab2" onclick="tab('tab2')">  <a>otras</a> </li>
</ul>

<div id="Content_Area">

    <div id="tab1">
        <p class="notas">Showing last alerts</p>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td style="color:blue">Alert</td>
                <td style="color:blue">User</td>
            </tr>
            <?php
                while ( $row = $result->fetch_array() ){

                   echo "<tr><td>".$row['DESCRIPTION']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['EMAIL']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['SUB_SECCION']."</td></tr>";                   
                }
            }
            else
                echo "error on query: ".$conx->error;
            }//else
            ?>
        </table>        
    </div>

    <div id="tab2" style="display: none;"> 
         <!-- We set its display as none because we don’t want to make this
             tab visible by default. The only visible/active tab should 
             be Tab 1 until the visitor clicks on Tab 2. -->
        <p>This is the text for tab 2.</p>
    </div>

    </div> <!-- End of Content_Area Div -->
     </div> <!-- End of Tabs Div -->

     </div>
```

CSS creates tabs, but for the moment only the first has the table the other just one line of text, but the table is inside this tab div
**archivo css**

```
 .contenido {  
 color: black;/*#333*/
 background-color: #F2F2E6;

 margin: 0px 0px 5px 0px;
 padding: 10px;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;

 width: 75%;/*678px;*/
 height: 480px;

 float: right; 
 display: inline; 
 }

   #Tabs ul {
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
margin-left: 10px;
list-style-type: none;
   }

   #Tabs ul li {
display: inline-block;
clear: none;
float: left;
height: 24px;
    }

  #Tabs ul li a {
position: relative;
margin-top: 16px;
display: block;
margin-left: 6px;
line-height: 24px;
padding-left: 10px;
background: #f6f6f6;
z-index: 9999;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
border-bottom: 0px;

/*  make the top left and top right corners of each tab rounded. */
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 4px;
border-top-left-radius: 4px;
-moz-border-radius-topright: 4px;
border-top-right-radius: 4px;
/* end of rounded borders */

width: 130px;
color: #000000;
text-decoration: none;
font-weight: bold;
       }

   #Tabs ul li a:hover {
text-decoration: underline;  
color:red;
    }

    #Tabs #Content_Area { 
   /* this is the css class for the content displayed in each tab */
padding: 0 15px;
clear:both;
overflow:hidden;
line-height:19px;
position: relative;
top: 20px;
z-index: 5;
height: 150px;
overflow: hidden;
      }

     p { padding-left: 15px; }
```

Comment: You should be posting your entire code, including CSS. Use http://www.pastebin.com if you have to, then include the link in your question if you have too much code.

Comment: This >>> `height: 480px;` may be your problem. Try to set it to `height: auto;` or `height: 100%;`, or to a higher pixel size, `height: 800px;` as an example (TEST). Try that and get back to me.

Comment: Does the php seem to be giving all results when you view source?

Comment: and make sure that `echo $result->num_rows;` returns more then `5`

Comment: If your database is not the issue, you could also set your results inside an `iframe`, with scrollbars that would show up if it's at a certain height.

Comment: at phpmyadmin it returns all the 12 rows

Comment: @WeaponX Have you tried my suggestion? (second comment from the top)

Comment: yes the height values doesn't affect the results, as for iframes that's new for me i will give it a try

Comment: @WeaponX Ok. Well, since the CSS you posted is not your full stylesheet, I suggest you check out all your `height` attributes for your DIVs that are related to your results' content, before trying `iframe`.

Comment: OH yeah that's correct, the height adjusment just work, thanks men, i really need to sleep. but where do i say question solved?

Comment: @WeaponX This `height: 150px;` and `overflow: hidden;` in `#Tabs #Content_Area` could also be a factor. Since you have `overflow: hidden;` set to **"hidden"**, could be a factor. Try changing it to `overflow:scroll;` or `overflow:visible;` to see if that works, and/or changing the heights to a higher number for those IDs. Try different variations.

Comment: @WeaponX Great news! I have to put in an answer and then you accept it with the checkmark.

Comment: @WeaponX Answer posted. Glad it worked out for you and happy I was of help. And you're quite welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The problem is inside your CSS.**

`height: 150px;` and `overflow: hidden;` in `#Tabs #Content_Area` could be factor.

Since you have `overflow: hidden;` set to **"hidden"**, it could be a factor.

Try changing it to `overflow:scroll;` or `overflow:visible;` to see if that works, and/or changing the heights to a higher number for those IDs.

Try different variations.

Answer (score 0):

I see a two possible causes:

1. The database query only returns 5 results
2. the DIV is not large enough, and even though the table ends up in,
       say, 25 records, the first 5 are only displayed and the rest are
       hidden by the boundaries of DIV.

It would help if you put some more `PHP` code or even the `CSS` of the `#area`.